# How many functions $g:A\to A$ are there such that $g(g(x))=x$ and $g(x)-x$ is not divisible by $3$ where $A=\{1,2,3,\dots,12\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, contest-math

My friend shared the following problem with me. The problem is from Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad 2021 (Divisional round).

> Let $ A=\{1,2,3,\dots,12\}$. How many functions $g:A\to A$ are there such that $g(g(x))=x$ and $g(x)-x$ is not divisible by $3$?

Here is my progress in solving the problem:

We partition the sets modulo $3$. Let $A_0=\{3,6,9,12\}$, $A_1=\{1,4,7,10\}$, $A_2=\{2,5,8,11\}$. Because $g(g(x))=x$ the function will be fixed if we fix the values of the function for $6$ numbers. Let $g(1)=k$, then $k\notin A_1$ and $g(k)=1$. This means $k$ can take $8$ values. Similar argument leads that $g(4)$, $g(7)$, $g(10)$ can take $7$, $6$ and $5$ values respectively.

I can't proceed from here because I need to find the number of values the function can take for $2$ more numbers for the function to be fixed. But I can say that the final answer will be greater than $8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5=1680$ from my approach.

From the comments, I realized that my approach is wrong. Then how do I solve the problem?

Comment: It's not as simple as you suggest.  If say $f(\{3,6,9,12\})=\{1,4,7,10\}$.  Then there is no place to put $f(2)$, say.

Comment: @lulu thank you for preventing me from making a fool of myself.  I was about to make the same analytical mistake that the OP did.

Comment: But that observation should point the way.  We see that group $A$ can not map onto group $B$, say. Ask yourself:   Is it possible for exactly three from $A$ to map to $B$?  Or must it be the case that two from $A$ map to $B$ and two map to $C$? That is easy to decide.   However it sorts out, I'd address those two cases separately.

Comment: $g$ is a bijection, so a permutation, so a product of disjoint cycles, and has no fixed points, so $g$ is a product of six transpositions. Each of the six transpositions is of the form $(a\ b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are not in the same $A_i$ (in the notation of the question). Furthermore, exactly two of the elements of $A_0$ must be paired with elements of $A_1$, and two with elements of $A_2$, and exactly two elements of $A_1$ must be paired with elements of $A_2$.

Comment: Please ask your friend the source of the question. We don't want to be answering questions from ongoing competitions here.

Comment: Since exactly $4$ of the $6$ pairs must involve $A_0$, there are exactly two pairs connecting $A_1$ to $A_2$.  Similarly there are exactly two connecting $A_0$ to $A_1$, and exactly two connecting $A_0$ to $A_2$.  The total number should then be ${{4}\choose{2}}\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2$ or $1728$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is from Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad Divisional round 2021 which is finished almost 6 months ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, $g(g(x))=x$ for all $x$, it is not hard to see that $g(x)$ must be a bijection with only $2$-cycles and $1$-cycles. Since $g(x)-x\not\equiv 0\mod 3$, we have that $g(x)\neq x$, hence, it must only have $2$-cycles.

So, now we can figure out how many ways there are to split the set $\{1,2,\ldots ,12\}$ into $6$ unordered pairs $\{a,b\}$ (we would then have $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=a$) such that each ordered pair satisfies $a\not\equiv b\mod 3$.

Now as you tried, split the set into $3$ sets $A_0,A_1,A_2$ depending on the elements equivalence in$\mod 3$. Note that if the number of unordered pairs containing an element from $A_0$ and $A_1$ is not $2$, then we will have to have at least one unordered pair that contains $2$ elements from $A_2$, which is not allowed.

Hence, by symmetry, we must have that there are exactly $2$ unordered pairs containing elements from sets $A_i$ and $A_j$ for $i,j\in \{0,1,2\}$

From there, it is straight forward counting. There are $\binom{4}{2}^2$ ways to pick the elements from sets $A_0$ and $A_1$ that will be together in an unordered pair. If those elements are $a,b\in A_0$ and $c,d\in A_1$, then there are $2$ ways to assign the pairs ($\{a,c\},\{b,d\}$ and $\{a,d\},\{b,c\}$.

For the remaining two elements in $A_0$, there are $4\cdot 3$ ways to assign elements of $A_2$ that will be paired with these elements of $A_0$.

Now for the pairings of the $2$ remaining elements of $A_1$ with those of $A_2$. There are exactly $2$ ways to assign these pairings.

So our total is $2\cdot \binom{4}{2}^2\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2=(12)^3=\boxed{1728}$

Comment: Nice! Another way to do the last calculation: for each $A_i$, there are $\binom 42$ ways to choose the two elements that are paired with $A_{i+1 \bmod 3}$. After that, for each pair $(A_i, A_j)$, there are two ways to pair up $a, b \in A_i$ with $c,d \in A_j$ now that we've already decided $\{a,b\}$ will be paired with $\{c,d\}$. This gives us $\binom 42^3 \cdot 2^3$.